# Raphael JS move/rotate group of drawings as one?

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, raphael

I have a little tool that draws up a grid of circles(representing holes) that allows the user to add text and lines to these circles.  Right now I have it set up so if the user clicks on any of the holes then wherever the hole is moved so is every other element on the Paper object.   What I am trying to implement next is the ability to rotate everything as one object.  I realize that for this to work that I need to know the central point of all the objects, which I can easily get.
     What I want to know is should I draw everything on another object.  This object will act as another Paper object of sorts, but will only serve for movement and rotation. Any click events on the holes drawn on the object will be passed on to the parent (i.e. the pseudo-paper object everything is drawn on).  Is this possible?  If so how would I draw everything onto say, a rectangle?  And if not what would be the best way to go implementing it?

Comment: Does each hole have its own paper? A jsfiddle link would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [Set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Set). You create it, push objects to it, and then treat it as an entire group, in your case by applying transformations.

Example:

```
var elements = paper.set();

if (!view.text) {
    view.text = App.R.text(0, 0, this.value);
    view.text.attr({
        'font-size': font_size,
    });
    elements.push(view.text);
}
elements.transform('something');
```

Note that you can also bind events to this entire set.